# How can we send a jquery amount filed in hidden in php for another page to retrieve the amount value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I've been trying to set the value of a hidden field in a form using jQuery, but without success.

Here is a sample code that explains the problem.

If I keep the input type to "text", it works without any trouble. But, changing the input type to "hidden", doesn't work !

```
<form method="POST" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        @ Brand1 <input type='text' id="amount4" class="form-control" name="Brand1"  readonly/>

        <br>
        <button type="submit" formaction="material-quote.php" name="quote1" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-left">Quote</button>
        <button type="submit" formaction="material-invoice.php" name="buynow1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="Brand1" value="" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>').change(function () {
        var number = $(this).val();
        //console.log(number);
        var o_val = $("#quantity<?=$x;?>").val();
        var op_val = number * o_val;
        $("#amounta<?=$x;?>").val(op_val);
        var amount4_total = 0;
        var amount5_total = 0;
        var amount6_total = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
            amount4_total += Number($(`#amounta${i}`).val());
            amount5_total += Number($(`#amountb${i}`).val());
            amount6_total += Number($(`#amountc${i}`).val());
            console.log($(`#amounta${i}`).val());
        }
        // console.log(amount4_total);
        $('#amount4').val(amount4_total);
    });

</script>
```

My error is how we can pass the amount value in hidden filed for next page

in my next page they will nothing can be show.

Here i will write the code of my project and console it work fine

Comment: You have duplicates names in your form. Both inputs, text and hidden, are named `amount4`.

Comment: hidden field name `name="amount4"` and text input field name are same. please change the name.

Comment: Change Id and name of  hidden field.
<input type="hidden" name="amount5" value="amount5" id="amount5" />
Change this also in javascript

Comment: I fixed your indentation to make it clearer to read. Please consider doing this yourself in the futur

Comment: There is no id starting by `unit_pricea` in the shown HTML. Please show relevant code.

Comment: Duplicate field amount4. try to run using one of them.Hope it will work

Comment: i have change and run but not working

Comment: still name are duplicated `Brand1`

Comment: ^ that, and **do not** fix your code in your question.

Comment: ok i am fixed in my localhost but still same error will came

Comment: here i am change my code like this                                                                       @ Brand1 <input type='text' id="amount4" class="form-control" name="br"  readonly/>   and also hidden type  <input type="hidden" name="br1" value="" /> change

Comment: `$('#amount4')` this is not mentioned in hidden field

Comment: $('#amount4') this is not mentioned in hidden field – Vel sir value not pass in that hidden filed that was i am asking

Comment: can u show me how to pass hidden value @vel

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="br1" value="" />` - there's a simple problem here: you didn't give your hidden field an ID, so it's hard for you to use jQuery to select it. Give it an ID, and then use jQuery to select that ID and write to it, just like your textbox. It's exactly the same process. e.g. `<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" name="br1" value="" />` and then `$("#hidden1").val("whatever-you-want");`. And then, when you submit the form, in the PHP the value from the hidden field will be in `$_POST["br1"]` (because you gave it that `name` attribute in the form).

Comment: keep the input field as text and add inline style="display:none" or create a class with "display:none" and add it in the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once check this code

```
<script>
 $('#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>').change(function () {
             var number = $(this).val();
               //console.log(number);
                var o_val = $("#quantity<?=$x;?>").val();
                var op_val = number * o_val;
               $("#amounta<?=$x;?>").val(op_val);
               var amount4_total = 0;
               for (var i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
                 amount4_total += Number($(`#amounta${i}`).val());
                 console.log($(`#amounta${i}`).val());
               }
              // console.log(amount4_total);
             $('#amount4').val(amount4_total);
             $("#brand_val").val(amount4_total);
             });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

i added `brand_val` id to the hidden field. and get the value by id.

```
<form method="POST" id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    @ Brand1 <input type='text' id="amount4" class="form-control" name="Brand1"  readonly/>

    <br>
    <button type="submit" formaction="material-quote.php" name="quote1" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-left">Quote</button>
    <button type="submit" formaction="material-invoice.php" name="buynow1" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right">Buy Now</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="brand_val" value="" id="brand_val"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#unit_pricea<?=$x;?>').change(function () {
    var number = $(this).val();
    //console.log(number);
    var o_val = $("#quantity<?=$x;?>").val();
    var op_val = number * o_val;
    $("#amounta<?=$x;?>").val(op_val);
    var amount4_total = 0;
    var amount5_total = 0;
    var amount6_total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
        amount4_total += Number($(`#amounta${i}`).val());
        amount5_total += Number($(`#amountb${i}`).val());
        amount6_total += Number($(`#amountc${i}`).val());
        console.log($(`#amounta${i}`).val());
    }
    // console.log(amount4_total);
    $("#brand_val").val(amount4_total);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: in another page it will display like this [object Object] @vel

Comment: console.log($("#brand_val").val($('#amount4').val(amount4_total))); then the console value is [object object] .

Comment: @Vel when you submit this form to PHP, the value from the hidden field will be in `$_POST["brand_val"]` (due to the name attribute on the hidden field). So you can get that value, and then include it in your HTML output like any other variable. If you already know about HTML forms and PHP then this is the same process as you use to read any other submitted field. The fact that it was a hidden field on the HTML form makes no difference to that.

Comment: actually i have two input fields one input filed value can u updated if another input value first one change automatically second one also change how

Comment: My Next page code is like this :   
print_r($_POST);
echo $brand_val;
//var_dump($_REQUEST);
if(isset($quote1) && $_POST["brand_val"])
{

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `material_quote`(`ma_quote_id`, `ma_user_id`, `ma_brand_id`, `ma_category`, `ma_product_name`, `ma_qty`, `ma_brand`, `ma_unit_price`, `ma_amount`,`ma_total_quote`);

Comment: @WebengersInfo "actually i have two input fields one input filed value can u updated if another input value first one change automatically second one also change how" ...if you're talking about doing this on a web page, then you do it by handling a JavaScript "change" event on the first field. You can find hundreds of examples of it online already. But actually that's **exactly** the same thing you are already doing here - right now you handle the "change" event of the unit_price field and then update the amount fields in response. You already know how to do the thing you're asking about.

Comment: @WebengersInfo if that's not what you mean then you'll have to give us a clearer indication of the problem. It's not clear to me how you think showing us a little bit of PHP from your next page is relevant. Are you asking how to change a PHP variable??

Comment: i am write that code but @vel can write code hidden then the second input filed not show the amount

Comment: Are you getting the value in `print_r($_POST);`?

Comment: @WebengersInfo "the second input filed" ...what and where is the second input field? You haven't shown it in your code as far as I can see. Again please be 100% clear on what you are talking about. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: yes i get the value but amount4 value not getting so that once see the updated code

Comment: @WebengersInfo Surely it's obvious, just add another line like `$("#amount4").val(amount4_total);` (just after the line `$("#brand_val").val(amount4_total);`). Then both fields are updated. It's a simple repetition of the same code, just with a different ID. You need to start to be able to see the patterns here if you are going to succeed! But then again, if you want to put the same value in both fields, why do you need two fields at all? The server doesn't need to receive the same value twice.

Comment: @WebengersInfo no problem. But please answer me:  if you want to put the same value in both fields, why do you need two fields at all? The server doesn't need to receive the same value twice.

Comment: Glad to help you.